# VS2012 Publisher Works, MSBUILD doesn't

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a web project that I can publish without a problem using the Visual Studio web publisher:

[image]

However, when I try to run publish from the console JUST using msbuild, it fails. This is the command I use:

```
msbuild "C:\xxxxx\xxxxx.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=C:\yyyyyy\xxxx.pubxml
```

The error I get is (after getting pretty far in the build):

[image: msbuild chokes]

Comment: look in the `obj\Release` directory and see where web.config is being placed (if anywhere).  It looks like msbuild can't find it in the expected location

Comment: Not sure why it's asking for a web.config or where to get it. Why does it work fine under the Web Publisher though?